# UTF8 encoding problem, same results work fine in wordpress

Tags: encoding, utf-8

I have a wordpress installation that clients can edit, all characters display ok. On the main homepage I query the same database for the same title and post content, but it doesn't display correctly - just a question mark

I have tried sending the utf8 headers manually, through htaccess and through meta tags. I have used SET name UTF8 (which turns the characters into the diamond symbol with a questionmark inside).

I genuinely cant figure out what it could be now and I really need these characters to display correctly.

Heres the homepage, you can see in the Sounddhism 6 preview that there are lots of question marks, if you click on it you will see what they are meant to look like
http://nottingham.subverb.net

I have passed it through the validator and it gives me this error:

```
Sorry, I am unable to validate this document because on line 373 it contained one or more bytes that I cannot interpret as utf-8 (in other words, the bytes found are not valid values in the specified Character Encoding). Please check both the content of the file and the character encoding indication.
The error was: utf8 "\xA0" does not map to Unicode
```

Which, i appreciate is supposed to help me, but I don't know what to do about it. Especially since that line, the letter generating the error is supposed to be a space and is AFTER the offending question marks.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Looks like you have bytes which don't map to Unicode. Can you replace the offending characters with their Unicode equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Compare the encoding of both the back-end scripts in Wordpress and also your homepage script. If you're using IE, right-click the page and check the encoding. Sometimes it's set to "Auto-detect" and IE will often detect a different encoding for different pages, causing strange issues like this.

If you're not using IE, try using a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see exactly what encoding (and what bytes are being sent back and forth both in the back-end and your homepage script.

If forcing UTF-8 on your homepage script doesn't work, I would guess that the back-end is not using UTF-8.